# Android: Insert Bitmap to Images.Media always get black background

Tags: android, bitmap, transparency

I'm trying to insert images to Media but always get black background

This is my code

```
bitmap = (Bitmap) adapter.getItem(position);

Uri uri = Uri.parse(Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), 
    bitmap, null, null));

intent.setData(uri);
getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

This is what I got after inserting image

[image]

Actually the image has transparent background

How to make it to be transparent?
Already tried most of solution to remove black background but still no luck

Comment: Where and how do you get the bitmap?

Comment: Gridview from adapter that showing images.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have uri and showing black color as mentioned.Then just creat new uri variable like below to solve this black color issue:**

```
//your contentResolver uri....
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Images.  Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, null, null));
//creat new uri variable using previous one
Uri freshUri=Uri.parse(uri.getPath());
//set on imageview or use freshUri uri variable where you want
imageView.setImageURI(freshUri);
```

**or simply call function below:**

```
public Uri removeBlack(Uri uri){
return Uri.parse(uri.getPath());
}
```

Comment: It's not working, image won't opened, it said Couldn't find the image

Comment: Please post your full code therefore i can figure out your actual problem

Comment: Also let me know you want image from sdcard or from your project please explain clearly what are you trying to do???

Comment: I have an app that contains many images, for example I want to attach image from Gmail from my app using intent.get_content by passing bitmap